# Setting Local Notifications using Ionic Capacitor and Framework7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7, capacitor

I am using Ionic Capacitor and Framework7 for an application. I want to implement localnotifications using capacitor local notification plugin. However it gives me uncaught referenceError: LocalNotifications is not defined

```
//Importing plugin
import  {Plugins}  from '../node_modules/@capacitor/core';
const  {LocalNotifications}  = Plugins;

//Schedule Local Notifcations
LocalNotifications.schedule({
        notifications: [{
            title: "Title",
            body: "Body",
            id: 1,
            schedule: {
                at: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 5)
            },
            sound: 'res://audio/android/iphone_6.mp3',
            attachments: null,
            actionTypeId: "",
            extra: null
        }]
    });
```

uncaught ReferenceError: LocalNotifications is not defined

Answer (score 3):

Try to import `Plugins` like `import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';`

Comment: Just to build on what @igor_c mentioned it could be the way the plugin has been imported. you need to import the Plugins like suggested above and then extract the LocalNotifications instance from the Plugins like `const { LocalNotifications } = Plugins;` I'd the same issue on Android and this solution fixed it, I think it was to do with the way vscode was importing the libs...

Answer (score -1):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications

```
import { LocalNotifications } from '@capacitor/local-notifications';
```

```
const novaNotificacaoId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
          const dataHoraNotificacao = new Date();
          dataHoraNotificacao.setHours(19);
          dataHoraNotificacao.setMinutes(0);
          LocalNotifications.schedule({
            notifications: [{
                title: "Notificação",
                body: descricaoNotificacao,
                id: novaNotificacaoId,
                group:'Alerta',
                iconColor:'#eb445a',
                schedule: {
                  at: dataHoraNotificacao,
                  allowWhileIdle: true,
                  repeats: true,
                  every: "day",
                  count: 1
                }
              }]
          }).then(() => {});
```

Comment: this import worked for me